# gradle sonarqube plugin on non-java module

Tags: javascript, gradle, sonarqube

I have multi-module gradle project as shown here

```
prj-root
    -prj-react-js
        -src/main/web
    -prj-java
         -prj-java-mod-1
             -src/main/java
         -prj-java-mod-2
             -src/main/java
```

The `prj-react-js` module is javascript module and only `plugin id 'base'` is applied in its gradle file. 
The sonarqube server is running on remote server.

The sonarqube plugin configuration in the root `prj-root/build.gradle` is very simple as shown here. There are no other configurations.

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.8"
}
```

When I run `gradle sonarqube` only the java code gets analyzed. I also require the javascript code to be analyzed. What configuration am I missing? Is there something to be enabled on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**:
The below configuration solved my issue.
**Explanation**:
The javascript module had sources in the `src/main/web` directory which I guess the sonarqube plugin do not analyze implicitly. Setting the property `sonar.sources` to `src/main/web` will trigger analysis of all javascript code in this directory and below.

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.8"
}


allprojects {
}

project(":prj-react-js") {
    sonarqube {
        properties {
            property "sonar.sources", "src/main/web"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using kotlin dsl. In the root project's build.gradle.kts file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

plugins {
    id("org.sonarqube") version ("2.8") apply false
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "org.sonarqube")
}
```

Now run the task `./gradlew sonarqube`